# Постоянно падает сайт

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Постоянно с периодичностью дня 2-3 . **Падает сайт** на вордпресс то пишет

> "Error establishing a database connection"

или же просто выдает установку вордпресс с самого начала.

Сайт никто не трогает и в админку не заходит.

Подскажите что в этом случае делать?

Comment: Читать логи? Смотреть потребление ресурсов?

Comment: Добавлю к вышесказанному: оптимизировать ВП и возможно менять хостинг.

Comment: @SeVlad скорее всего, менять хостинг. Если переходит на установку wp, значит, накрылась база. WP этого не может (ну или over вирусня). Скорее всего, хостинг теряет базу.